# How to check whether Content Database is read-only or not?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, database, content-database

How to check whether **Content Database is read-only** or not using client context ? we can easily get using server object model but how to do this with **Client Object Model**

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, using the existing services; it is not possible to access the content database informations from Client Object model or services. As a work around you can create your own WCF service and deploy it in SharePoint, which can provide your required data.

1. [How to Customize WCF Services in SharePoint 2010](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1404-how-to-customize-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010/)
2. [SharePoint 2010: Create Custom WCF Service](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html)